# Importing Alamofire in Project that targets iOS 7

Tags: alamofire

I checked the new Alamofire installation steps.

Since I need to target iOS 7.0 I wonder if importing the `Alamofire.swift` is enough to make it works or not?

Why the documentation states to wrap the functions around a `Struct Alamofire`? is that needed to call functions as they were within a Namespace? and in that case have I to wrap the whole file or single functions?

Answer (score 8):

You just have to add this:

```
//put this on alamofire.swift, then call it as Alamofire.manager.your_method
struct Alamofire {
static let manager = Manager.sharedInstance
}
```

And after you can use on this way:

```
Alamofire.manager.request(.GET, videoUrl, parameters: ["foo": "bar"])
            .response { (request, response, data, error) in
                println(request)
                println(response)
                println(error)
        }
```

Comment: This is the best way to make AF work with iOS 7 - @mattergoal you should accept it

Comment: for things like these apple is a real piece of sh*

Answer (score 1):

So with the [readme.md](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) + some scouring of comments on their issues, the instructions we find are wrapping all of the top level members in

```
struct Alamofire {
    all original code ...
}
```

but in reality this doesn't seem to work *quite* that easily.

The whole file is pretty big, so here's a gist (not mine) with modifications to make the basic idea work:
https://gist.github.com/ChocolateMinht/00aa610da1b4e6c4bed6

You are right in thinking that is needed to make the calls as if they are namespaced.

With the above you can just call `Alamofire.request(...)` as you would if it were imported as a framework in iOS 8+