# Alamofire with iOS 7

Tags: cocoapods, alamofire

I need to support iOS 7. I have Alamofire in my podspec file since it's an internal library for a separate I'm building. When I run `pod lib lint`, I get the following error:

```
The platform of the target `Pods` (iOS 7.0) is not compatible with `Alamofire (1.1.4)` which has a minimum requirement of iOS 8.0 - OS X 10.9.
```

When I try add the library to a regular Podfile of a project that supports iOS 7, I get the same error. Anyone know the issue?

Comment: check following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273673/importing-alamofire-in-project-that-targets-ios-7

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dynamic Frameworks won't work in iOS 7.  Drag the file in manually.

Quote from AlamoFire's [README](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#installation):

> Embedded frameworks require a minimum deployment target of iOS 8 or OS X Mavericks.
>
> To use Alamofire with a project targeting iOS 7, you must include the Alamofire.swift source file directly in your project. See the 'Source File' section for instructions.
>
> For Swift 1.2 using the Xcode 6.3 Beta, use the xcode-6.3 branch.

Comment: ah. I can't believe I missed that.

Comment: Will this every get fixed somehow? By apple or cocoapods finding a workaround?

Comment: @Esq - I don't think so as Apple won't update and there's not much benefit in supporting iOS 7 at this point w iOS 9 right around the corner.

Comment: Seems that iOS 7 is no longer supported by Alamofire, even with manual installation .. Do I need to go back to AFNetworking if I need iOS 7 ?

Comment: @someone0 You could do that, or, you could probably look through history to the commit before they dropped 7 support and use that version.